# Export DOM elements for testing with Selenium

Tags: selenium, dom, qtp

All,

I tried searching existing posts but could not find a direct answer, bear with me

I am trying to find if there is any tool that extracts all DOM elements on the page (links, images,buttons and labels) and possibly export them into Excel spreadsheet

Purpose: for Selenium testing >>  finding each element on developer tool like using inspect element or firebug is taking long time , but instead if there is a way export all of them to excel so it will be faster when coding

ex: Object Repository in QTP does well for this, but finding similar in Selenium

thanks

Comment: Maybe it'll help to understand the purpose? Are you trying to check every single element on the page? Are you using this as a lookup? This sounds a bit heavyweight for most purposes.

Comment: Hi there,  the purpose is to build xpaths for all the elements , not by absolute xpath but construct them reasonably with name, id or other attributes.. (my problem that, the DIV changes all the time (ex: one user there are only 5 text boxes but other user there are 6 text boxes, so using xpath absolute is failing)

Comment: and to build xpath, I guess if we got all the DOM elements in Excel so it will be easy to construct xpaths for them

Comment: I don't understand why exporting the entire DOM to Excel is going to help build XPaths. The entire DOM is already in the browser and the dev tools exist to help you try things quickly and make sure they work. You don't really want to find every element on the page, only the ones that you plan to interact with. Why don't you post some of the relevant HTML that you having issues creating locators for.

Comment: This seems like a complicated way to get around getting used to using dev tools, and it would provide little benefit IMO. Your time would probably be better spent trying to get more efficient using dev tools to identify and construct selectors.

Comment: totally agreed , thank you all

Answer (score 0):

Finding all elements inside a page might not be too helpful as you still need to check which xpath represent which element in the page.

As others said, your time would probably better spend to get more efficient way of using devtools to construct selector that you want to interact with. There are also many xpath helper plugins available which will help you achieve things faster like https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xpath-helper/hgimnogjllphhhkhlmebbmlgjoejdpjl?hl=en, https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/selectorgadget/mhjhnkcfbdhnjickkkdbjoemdmbfginb?hl=en